# Android Nav Drawer w/ Account Picker

Tags: android, material-design

Google has an account picker built into the header of the material design navigation drawer. Details can be found at their [design spec docs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

An example can be seen in the new Hangouts app shown below.

[image: Hangouts account picker]

**Is there a pre-written module that you can insert into your own Android app or does this need to be rebuilt from scratch?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no pre-written module from Android for this, but you can use this good library: [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)